# EMPTY SESSION MANY TIMES PHP

Tags: php, session

I make this post because I am really confused about session in PHP. I have a page (index.php) and I save in session a lot of variables (for example, one of this is `$_SESSION["FID"]`) and i redirect the user in a third party iframe. When the user enter successful his data in iframe, the iframe redirects the user again in index.php and also saves in session other variables.
When the user enters again in index.php I check the session, which comes from iframe (every time the session is set) and after that I make a check if $_SESSION["FID"] isset.

The problem is that most of the times (regardless the browser or something else),  `$_SESSION["FID"]` is empty. Why is this happening? How can I find a solution in this?

I 've tried to be clear and not to confuse you.

Comment: "Hey, my car is broken." - "Oh, thats bad, can i see it so i might be able to fix it." - "No, i wont let you see it ò_Ó."

Comment: That means "I want code if you want help" if you didnt get it.

Comment: did you have session_start() ?

Answer (score 0):

You must put `session_start();` at the top of every page you want you `$_SESSION` data to exist.